# how to revert a range of commits without getting asked for the commit message each time?

Tags: git

when I used to revert a range of commits, it didn't stop for approving each commit message one by one but recently it stops and opens my vs code to approve the commit message ( this behaviour happens on my unconflicted and non-empty commits, so I see no reason for this stoppage), so is there a way to tell git to pick each target commit message for its reverted version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [--no-edit](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt---no-edit).

```
git revert <commits> --no-edit
```

If you use a GUI client, I think you can find an option equivalent to `--no-edit` on the revert menu.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could take advantage of environment variables:

```
GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true git revert blah blah
```

That should avoid the editor from popping up at all.

Comment: where should I type this line of command?@eftshift0

Comment: I would use that in `bash`.

Comment: after typing this command in bash this, `git revert -h` popped up.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. It has to be `/bin/true`. Sorry.